Next.js with Typescript and Auth.js v5 - How Can I make sure that a user is logged in on a page that uses "use client"?
My background is from React+Python Flask app. I am now converting a website to Next.js without the Python Flask app.
The website is going to be created with Next.js v15.
Currently I am implementing Auth.js v5.
My user can login using Google and this Works great.
My question is how can I check if the user is logged in or not when I have a page With "use client";.
For example I have a page app/(private)/customers/page.tsx which shows a list of customers that uses the Client Components.
app/(private)/customers/page.tsx
For example I have a page named app/(private)/customers/page.tsx which uses the "use client";. How can I in this page check that the user is logged in?
"use client";
import { authConfig } from "@/app/lib/auth";
import { loginRequiredClient } from "@/app/lib/loginRequiredClient";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import Link from "next/link";
import useSWR from "swr";

export default async function Dashboard() {
  // Get my user
  await loginRequiredClient();
  const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);

  // Get customers
  const { data: customersData, error: customersError, isLoading: customersIsLoading } = useSWR("/customers/api-customers/api-get-customers/");
  if (customersError) return <div className="error_smal"><span>Failed to load</span></div>;
  if (customersIsLoading) return ( <div><div className="loading"></div><span>Loading...</span></div> );

  // Return
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Customers</h1>
      <ul>
          
      {customersData?.data.map((customer: CustomerI) => (
          <li className="list-none" key={customer.customer_id}>
          <p>{customer.customer_name}</p>
          </li>
       ))}

      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

app/(private)/customers/api-customers/api-get-customers/route.ts
import { authConfig } from "@/app/lib/auth";
import { sql } from "@/app/lib/db";
import { loginIsRequiredServer } from "@/app/lib/loginIsRequiredServer";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // Get my user
  await loginIsRequiredServer();
  const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);
  
  // Fetch customers from database
  const res = await sql(
    `SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customers_index
    ORDER BY customer_name ASC;`
  );

  return NextResponse.json({ data: res.rows });
}

app/lib/auth.ts
import { NextAuthOptions, User, getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { sql } from "./db";

export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
    
      // Check if user exists in the database
      const res = await sql(
        "SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_middle_name, user_last_name FROM c_users_index WHERE user_email=$1",
        [user.email]
      );
      if (res.rowCount == 0) {
        // User does not exist
        console.log(`app/lib/auth.ts::authConfig()::User not found ${user.email}`);
        
        return false;
      }
      const sqlMyUser = res.rows[0]
      
      // User exists
      return true;
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      // Add additional properties to the session here if needed
      return session;
    }
  }
};

app/lib/loginIsRequiredServer.ts
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function loginIsRequiredServer() {
    const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);
    if (!session) return redirect("/");
  }

app/lib/loginRequiredClient.ts
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

// Custom hook to check if login is required
export function loginRequiredClient() {
  const session = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && !session) {
    router.push("/");
  }
}

app/lib/db.ts
import { Client, QueryResult } from "pg";
import { loadEnvConfig } from "@next/env";

const projectDir = process.cwd();
loadEnvConfig(projectDir)

// Generate a Postgres client
export async function getClient(): Promise<Client>{
    // console.log("db.ts::getClient()::Init");

    // Client with URL
    if (process.env.DB_URL) {
        // console.log("db.ts::getClient()::Connecting client with URL"); //  + "?sslmode=require"
        const client = new Client({
          connectionString: process.env.DB_URL,
        });
        // console.log("db.ts::getClient()::Connecting client with URL [connected]");
        return client;
    }

    // Client with username, host, database, password
    // console.log("db.ts::getClient()::Connecting client with username, host, database, password");
    const client = new Client({
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT!)
    });
    // console.log("db.ts::getClient()::Connecting client with username, host, database, password [connected]");
    return client;
}

// Handle connection, SQL and end the connection
export async function sql(sql: string, values?: Array<any>): Promise<QueryResult<any>> {
    // console.log("db.ts::sql()::Querying");
    const client = await getClient();
    await client.connect();
    // console.log("db.ts::sql()::Querying Connect");
    const res = await client.query(sql, values);
    // console.log("db.ts::sql()::Querying Await client query");
    await client.end();
    // console.log("db.ts::sql()::Querying [OK]");
    return res;
}


First, you have to wrap the entire application root, or the desired application root (Which is the layout.tsx) with the SessionProvider
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import type { ReactNode } from "react";

interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default async function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

Then in your client-side page
"use client"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/UserAvatar"
 
export default function Dashboard() {
  const session = useSession()
 
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringfy(session)}
    </div>
  )
}

You can check if the session is null.
